# Missing base directory for file set: null (included: [], excluded: [])

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-6

soy desarrollador Front End pero tengo que dar mantenimiento a un proyecto Spring MVC in java 6 (jdk 6u43), spring (3.2.2.RELEASE). Este proyecto contiene dos librerias modificadas .jar por el antiguo desarrollador.

Use maven para instalar las librerias con documentación que encontre con el comando Dfile.

```
Maven: mvn Dfile=.....
```

Para hacer el build uso el comando `mvn clean install` pero obtengo este error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project cfo-scoreboard: Missing base directory for file set: null (included: [], excluded: []) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Hi @RafaelH , this is StackOverflow in spanish, please change the language of your question or ask it in StackOverflow english community.